# Ubuntu and other Debian derived distros not booting

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, debian

I've tried Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Debian, even though all have worked great for me I'm keeping with Ubuntu, I tested 12.04, 12.10 and even 13.04. The 12.04 LTS is the one I work with.

There's one issue persisting in the three distros I've tested, sometimes at *random* occasions the boot fails, after GRUB, it shows only a `_` as prompt remaining indefinitely, I've let pass up to an hour, and best I could do was to wait for a while and try again until I get it to load.

Everytime this happens and I've selected **recovery mode** I get logs like these:

[image: Once I got this output] 
[image]

So, I blame the last line:

> **[ 0. .... ]Booting Node 0, Processors #1**

to be the *issue*, all first log lines appear continuously but it'll stop then.

I already updated BIOS, but there's something I think it might be the *issue* and that's the Hyperthreading, I had disabled it after BIOS update and it stopped happening, now I enabled it for installing a 64 bits OS in VMWare Player and it happened again.

Last I tried: editing the /boot/grub/grub.conf by adding acpi=ht in the Ubuntu menu entry, not working. I googled and I've not really found a solution.

Comment: Have you tried 32bit instead of 64bit?  Have you tried disabling any multi-cpu settings in your BIOS?

Comment: Well I disabled Hyper Virtualization, and I didn't try for multiple CPU settings in BIOS.